# ¿Qué debo hacer si me arroja un error numpy.ndarray? Python

Tags: python

```
x = np.arange(0,5*pi,0.01*pi)
y = np.cos(x)  # Funcion a derivar 

h = x[4]-x[3]  # define h.

der = []
x2 = []
for i in range(len(y)-1):
      der.append( (y[i+2]-2.0*y[i+1]+y(i))/h**2)# formula para derivada.
      x2.append( x[i])

der = np.array(der)  # tenga la misma dimension
x2 = np.array(x2)      


der3 = []
x3 = []
for i in range(len(y)-2):
       der3.append( (-y[i+3]+4.0*y[i+2]-5.0*y[i+1]+2*y(i))/(h**2))  # formula.
       x3.append( x[i])      

der3 = np.array(der3)  # tenga la misma dimension
x3 = np.array(x3)

plt.plot( x, y, 'g',x2, der, 'r',x3, der3, 'b')
```

Comment: Saludos, para que tu pregunta sea aceptada y respondida debes añadir un poco más de información (ej. cual es el error que obtienes, explicación breve de que es lo intentas hacer) de esta forma varios podrán comprender lo que intentas hacer y podran ayudarte de mejor forma ;). Te invito a revisar la seccion [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas con el código:

- Las formulas para `der` y `der3` escriben `y(i)` donde tendría que ser `y[i]`.
- La formula para `der` emplea `y[i + 2]`. El valor máximo de `i` es `len(y) - 2` y en este caso la formula intenta emplear `y[len(y)]` pero este valor no existe: el último elemento de `y` es `y[len(y)-1]`. Por eso, el bucle tendría que parar un paso antes. Lo mismo pasa con `der3` que también tendría que parar antes.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pi = np.pi
x = np.arange(0, 5 * pi, 0.01 * pi)
y = np.cos(x)  # Funcion a derivar

h = x[4] - x[3]  # define h.

der = []
x2 = []
for i in range(len(y) - 2):
    der.append((y[i + 2] - 2.0 * y[i + 1] + y[i]) / h ** 2)  # formula para derivada.
    x2.append(x[i])

der = np.array(der)  # tenga la misma dimension
x2 = np.array(x2)

der3 = []
x3 = []
for i in range(len(y) - 3):
    der3.append((-y[i + 3] + 4.0 * y[i + 2] - 5.0 * y[i + 1] + 2 * y[i]) / (h ** 2))  # formula.
    x3.append(x[i])

der3 = np.array(der3)  # tenga la misma dimension
x3 = np.array(x3)

plt.plot(x, y, 'g', x2, der, 'r', x3, der3, 'b')
```

El código genera el siguiente plot. Las curvas azul y rojo coinciden practicamente, resultando en un efecto morado.

[image: el plot]